# Linear Transformations from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation

Is my iff statement correct?

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a Linear Transformation iff there exists a unique $a\in\mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb R$, $f(x)=xf(a)$

So if I am given any linear transformation from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ it should be of this form right?

Comment: This is true for $f\neq 0$. If $f=0$, $a$ is not unique [for example, in this case: $\;0=f(3)=3f(5)=3f(14)$].

Comment: In general, $\;0=f(x)=xf(5)=xf(14)$.

Comment: Yes it's not true for zero transformation.But for non zero transformation how do I prove the uniqueness? Existence is clear but what about uniqueness.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to say thta $f$ is linear iff $f(x) = ax$ for a unique $a \in \Bbb R$ and moreover $a = f(1)$

If $f$ is linear
$$f(x) = f(x  1) = x \ f(1)$$
so $a = f(1)$

If $f(x) = ax$  then you can easily check that it is linear and $f(1) = a$
$$f(x + y) = a (x + y) = ax + ay = f(x) + f(y)$$
$$f(bx) = abx = bax = b f(x)$$
for every $x,y,b \in \Bbb R$

Comment: So my statement is correct?For Proof of direct part just choose a=1 and we would be done.Converse is as you have proved above @osecnarf ittorettul

Comment: @Shashank Yes the first line of my answer means that if $f$ is linear then can be written as $f(x) = f(1)x$ for every $x \in \Bbb R$

Comment: @Shashank  A better statement could be: $f$ is linear iff $f(x) = ax$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, then you have $a = f(1)$ as a consequence of linearity

Comment: @Shashank $a$ is an arbitrary real number

Comment: @Shashank No, $f$ is linear iff it is of the form $f(x) = ax$ for a unique real number $a$, you cannot fix $a$ a priori, it depends on the linear map $f$

Comment: Oh yes.Then my original statement is correct I suppose

Comment: @Shashank The idea behind the statement is correct but formally it isn’t, for example if you take $f$ to be the zero map then there is no a unique $a$ such that $f(x) = xf(a)$

Comment: @Shashank It is better to say that $f$ is linear iff there exist a unique $a \in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = ax$, note that $a$ has a different role now

Comment: @Shashank I edited the answer for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

**If $f\neq0$, $a$ is unique.**

If $f\neq0$ we can use the relation

$$ \dim(\ker(f))+\dim(\Im(f))=\dim(\Bbb R)=1. $$

If it were $\dim(\ker(f))=1$, we would have $\dim(\Im(f))=0$, hence $\Im(f)=\{0\}$, so $f=0$, excluded. Therefore $\ker(f)=\{0\}$, i.e. $f$ is injective.

Suppose then $f(x)=xf(a)=xf(b)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Putting $x=1$ (or any $x\neq 0$) we obtain $f(a)=f(b)$ and injectivity gives $a=b$.